# Accessing multiple levels of a deeply nested lists when a level has no name

Tags: r, purrr

I just can't seem to figure out how to access multiple elements of a list when one of the elements is nested at a different level and doesn't have a name. In the example below I can extract the title element easily enough:

```r
library(purrr)

obj1 <- list(resource = list(list(format = "a"), list(format = "b")), title = "blue")
obj2 <- list(resource = list(list(format = "y"), list(format = "z")), title = "red")

x <- list(foo = obj1, bar = obj2)

imap(x[1:length(x)], ~ {
  paste0(.y, ": ", .x[["title"]])
})
#> $foo
#> [1] "foo: blue"
#> 
#> $bar
#> [1] "bar: red"
```

<sup>Created on 2019-02-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

My goal though is to have an output which accesses these elements:

```
x[["foo"]][["resource"]][[1]][["format"]]
x[["foo"]][["resource"]][[2]][["format"]]
x[["bar"]][["resource"]][[1]][["format"]]
x[["bar"]][["resource"]][[2]][["format"]]
```

And then ultimately the output looks something like this:

```
#> $foo
#> [1] "foo: blue (a,b)"
#> 
#> $bar
#> [1] "bar: red (y,z)"
```

It seems like I should be able to do this within one purrr statement but I can't quite figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `purrr`, we can also use `pluck()` and `map` to get values from the list. This seems to return what you want

```
imap(x, ~paste0(
    .y, ": ", pluck(.x, "title"),
    " (", 
    paste0(map_chr(pluck(.x, "resource"), pluck, "format"), collapse=","), 
    ")"))
```

This returns

```
$foo
[1] "foo: blue (a,b)"
$bar
[1] "bar: red (y,z)"
```